# java swing thread problem

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

In my java swing application am having a Jframe and Jlabel for displaying current time.
here am using a thread for displaying time in jlablel which is added to the frame.my doubt is that when i dispose the jframe what will happen to the thread whether its running or stopped.

Comment: and what's the actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have NOT marked your thread as daemon by calling `yourThread.setDaemon(true)`, it will keep running even if main thread in your application has finished. Remember you have to call `setDaemon` before starting the thread.

Refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733890/end-java-command-line-application-properly/3733905#3733905) to some previous question for details.

The correct way in your case, I believe,  would be you maintain a 'stop' flag which is watched by your timer thread. Timer thread should exit on reading this flag as 'false'. You can add a WindowListener to your jframe and on the window closed event set the 'stop' flag to *true*

Heres example code for what I am suggesting :

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.start();

    JFrame jf = new JFrame("GOPI");
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setSize(100, 100);
    jf.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        t.stopTimer();
      }
    });
    System.out.println("JFrameTest.main() DONE");
  }
}

class Timer extends Thread {
  boolean stop = false;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      if (stop)
        break;
      System.out.println("Counting :" + i);
    }
    System.out.println("Timer exit");
  }

  public void stopTimer() {
    stop = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd go one step further and use a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of a thread and call `stop()` on it in my `windowClosing(WindowEvent e)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread will keep running.

You need to either do as suggested by Gopi or you could use `System.exit(0)` in close operation of your JFrame.

NOTE: I am assuming here that Your application needs to end if this Frame is closed.

Comment: no i can't call the system.exit(0) it will close my application. i need to dispose the jframe and show a new jframe within a fraction of seconds.