# System.exit(1) instead of return

Tags: java

just found an example on Oracle site, they use System.exit() if console is == null, but I can't see why it is better than simple return. 
Here's the link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html

Comment: `System.exit(int)` sets the error level returned back to the process that ran the process, this provides the caller the opportunity to take appropriate action if the call fails for some reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit(1)` means you are exiting from System and setting exit code = 1 means an erroneous termination of the program

whereas `return;` will terminate that application with exit code = 0, which to the caller means the program terminated successfully

---

**Also See**

- [exiting functions in main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398732/exiting-functions-in-main)

Comment: yes, I understand it in case of some relatively complicated application but using it by Oracle in such simple tutorial class seems to me a bit strange :)

Comment: that is the only difference, probably the code was written from someone who came from long stay from c++

Answer (score 1):

System.exit(1) can be useful if you call your java program lets say from a bash script and you would like to react accordingly to success or failure of the java program.

Answer (score 1):

System.exit will shutdown all the executing threads, closing files, releasing resources, etc...  It terminates the JVM.

However, Return is used by an executing thread on a method, but if system.exit is used, a thread will never return.  So they are two different things that are used for different purposes.

See the Java 7 Oracle document [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29).