# How to check if one of the thread has failed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multi-threaded Java application. I want the whole application to fail is one of the thread encounters any exception.

I don't think doing `System.exit();` inside the thread will exit the whole app.

Can someone suggest a way?

Comment: the whole app or you simply want to stop all your threads?

Comment: check this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3716015/1065180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `try-catch` in Thread's run method and in catch block `System.exit(0);` it works.

Answer (score 1):

actually, calling `System.exit()` *will* exit the whole app, but that's generally not what you want in your library code (for instance, it makes unit testing difficult).

a better implementation is to have a shared "error handler" reference, with an implementation that you control.  in unit tests, you could just log the exception.  in your real app, you could call `System.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do that is to have try{} catch{} on each thread, when you catch exception you may call static function that exits the application.