# Force-quitting an Android app in BlackBerry 10

Tags: android, blackberry-10

For Android, we had a very dirty workaround—don't ask, clients—that basically worked like this in the main activity. When `quitApp()` is called, the activity stack is cleared and the app exits completely.

```
public void quitApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
      finish();
    }
}
```

We've now packaged this app for BlackBerry 10, and everything else runs fine, except for this piece of code. What happens when `quitApp()` is called is that the activity refreshes (sometimes it goes to the app "exposé" thing in between) but in any case the app stays on-screen.

Is there any other workaround for force-quitting an Android app packaged for BB10?

Comment: 'Quitting' on Android is irrelevant as a concept

Comment: I know, that's why I mentioned it being a workaround and the fact that clients insisted on this behavior.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Since it's a Blackberry I will happily advice `System.exit(1);`

Comment: This *does* seem to do the trick. Would you please post this as an answer (and maybe an explanation of why this works on BB10 but not Android)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.exit(1);` will do it for you.

It is a system hook: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html

Discussed here: [When should we call System.exit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715967/when-should-we-call-system-exit-in-java)

Here is the Android Doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)

Why you shouldn't use System.Exit in Android is here: [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon?lq=1)