# System.exit(1) and return

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateTextFile
{
    private Formatter formatter;

    public void openFile()
    {
        try
        {
            formatter = new Formatter("clients.txt");
        }

        catch (SecurityException securityException)
        {
            System.err.println("You do not have permission to access this file");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
        {
            System.err.println("Error opening or creating the file");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void addRecords()
    {
        AccountRecord accountRecord = new AccountRecord();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n", "To terminate input, type the end-of-file indicator", "when you are prompted to enter input", "On Unix/Linux/Mac OS X type <control> d then press Enter", "On Windows type <ctrl> z then press Enter");

        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            try
            {
                accountRecord.setAccountNumber(scanner.nextInt());
                accountRecord.setFirstName(scanner.next());
                accountRecord.setLastName(scanner.next());
                accountRecord.setBalance(scanner.nextDouble());

                if (accountRecord.getAccountNumber() > 0)
                    formatter.format("%d %s %s %,.2f%n", accountRecord.getAccountNumber(), accountRecord.getFirstName(), accountRecord.getLastName(), accountRecord.getBalance());
                else
                    System.out.println("Account number must be greater than 0");
            }

            catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException)
            {
                System.err.println("Error writing to file");
                return;
            }

            catch (NoSuchElementException noSuchElementException)
            {
                System.err.println("Invalid input. Try again");
                scanner.nextLine();
            }

            System.out.printf("%s %s%n%s", "Enter account number (>0),", "first name, last name and balance.", "?");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public void closeFile()
    {
        if (formatter != null)
            formatter.close();
    }
}
```

I was just wondering why in `openFile()` the `catch` blocks are terminated with `System.exit()` and the `catch` blocks in `addRecords()` terminate with `return`. Is there a recommended way of when each should be used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They do different things. `return` simply returns from the function to its caller and the program continues running. `System.exit()` terminates the program; control does not return to the caller.

You should use `System.exit()` when your program encounters an *unrecoverable* error and there is no point in the program continuing to run. Use `return` when your program can gracefully recover, or when the program should perform cleanup/closeout actions before exiting.

See also this [more extended discussion of `System.exit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715967/when-should-we-call-system-exit-in-java).

Comment: Technically, a method should throw an exception if final cleanup may be needed, but good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` should have been a `break`, just leaving the while-loop, so that `scanner.close()` is done.

`System.exit` is bad style, but feasible for a command line program. Not catching the exception would be somewhat the same: termination with a message, but then with a stack trace too.
In this letting the function throw an exception would be the preferable way.

Answer (score 0):

**return** statement is used inside a method to come out of it.**System.exit(0)** is used in any method to come out of program.
**System.exit(0)** terminates the program narmally.Whereas **System.exit(1)** terminates the program because of some error encountered in the program.

Answer (score -3):

`System.exit()` terminates the program at the line of invocation.
`System.exit(1)` terminates the program if an error occurs.