# How to exit a method and terminate the program in java

Tags: java

I am struggling to understand why my code will not exit when I tell it to. I want the program to terminate when I tell it to. But in my block of code where I tell it to, it just ignores it then moves onto the next line of code. For example: (here is part of my code):

```
if (newNum - userNum == 0) {
    System.out.println("You loose!");
    System.exit(0);
    return;
} 

//computer picks
comPick = drawNum();

newNum = newNum - comPick;
System.out.println("The computer picks " + comPick + " number. There are " + newNum + ".");

if (newNum - comPick == 0) {
    System.out.println("You win! Computer Loses!");
    System.exit(0);
    return;
}
```

When newNum - userNum equals zero it just skips over all of my code and moves onto the next block. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. But making a method terminate the program is *usually* a bad idea, to be honest - it's a better idea for the normal flow of the logic to do that. To put it another way: this code is going to be relatively painful to unit test...

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should we call System.exit in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715967/when-should-we-call-system-exit-in-java)

Comment: wild guess: newNum and userNum are `float` or `double`? :)

Comment: What @Affe said; also, no need to `return` if you `System.exit()`!

Comment: only with a crystal ball to know