# Update a Jar File while running in windows

Tags: java, file, jar, jvm

So, when my jar file runs, I want it to delete and rewrite it from a site. Windows locks the files, even though the JVM is done with it. Is there anyway to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Propably you've created multiple threads and haven't called System.exit(0); when your programm closes.
Note: The 0 indicates that everything went right.

See also [When should we call System.exit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715967/when-should-we-call-system-exit-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Is this for updating purposes? you could do a copy of your .JAR, then open this copy via command line to update the original file, when the update finishes, you could open the original .JAR passing a parameter to delete the copy, and that's it.

The code gets a little messy but i did it some time ago and it worked.