# Can we use System.exit() in java Web Applications

Tags: java, web-applications, systemexit

We are developing the web application using java. I want to use `System.exit()` in one of my methods instead of return. As per my knowledge, the application will go into shut down mode if I use this.

Could anybody give me suggestions on this?

Comment: *"Could any body give me suggestions on this."*  - I suggest that you DON'T DO IT.

Answer (score 5):

In general, this is a pretty terrible idea, but the rule of thumb is `System.exit()` shuts down the entire JVM.

Your web application should be able to handle responses rather than just kill itself, I don't know of a *good* scenario where you'd ever want it to kill itself.

Comment: Will it shutdown the JVM and the server also in which the application deplyos?

Comment: Yes, in as much as it'll shut down the container (Jboss / Tomcat / Glassfish) that also runs on the JVM.

Comment: If you are in development mode and you want to fail fast, `System.exit()` can be very helpful. Else you have to scroll back through log files to find out the root cause. Of course, you wouldn't use this in production mode.

Answer (score 5):

`System.exit()` will shutdown the Servlet Container / (Tomcat)
Similar question noted at [When should we call System.exit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715967/when-should-we-call-system-exit-in-java)