# How exactly works the Java application exit code of the main() method?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, exit-code

I have the following doubts related a simple command line Java application.

So I have this command line application that is started by a **`main()`** method defined inside a **Main** class. As usual this **`main()`** method is defined with this signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

It's return type is **`void`**, and that should mean it doesn't return any value. But when its execution correctly terminates I obtain following message in the IntelliJ console.

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54090', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What exactly does represent the **`exit code 0`**? I think it means that the program have correctly completed its execution without incur into any error.

So now I have the following 2 doubts:

1. If it is true why it happens if my **`main()`** method return **`void`**?
2. How can I return a different exit code if my application ended with an error?

Is there a standard exit code value for ending with errors?

Comment: Please read the documentation of the [`System` class, particularly `exit(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29).

Comment: The exit code 0 is just a 0 by the convention used for java. In a normal case an exit code other then 0 should be an indicator for an error, which does not need to be the case if the programmer behind the java programm did not follow this convention when using System.exit();

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The VM exits when

- all of the non-daemon threads stop running, or
- `System.exit(exitCode)` is called

In the first case, the exit code is 0. In the second case, it's the exit code passed to the `exit()` method.

Don't forget that even if your main() method returns, the program will continue running until no non-daemon thread runs anymore. And any thread running in the VM can choose to exit explicitely.

The exit code 0 means that everything went as expected. you can choose to use any other exit code to signal an exceptional condition to the environment.

Comment: Ok, tnx. Maybe mine is a stupid question but what exactly is a "non daemon threads"?

Comment: A daemon thread is a thread that automatically stops running when the last "normal", non-daemon threads, stops running. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: This is not mentioned in the JLS
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.8

Answer (score 11):

Exit code of process is what process reports to operating system as its error code.

Java designers *could* make `main()` method to return `int` so that JVM could report to OS this value as a process exit code. But they decided to make main void but provide API that can update this code using `System.exit(exitCode)`. The advantage of this solution is that program can decide to exit at any point and in any thread, not only in main method and in main thread.

Comment: Your point "The advantage of this solution is that program can decide to exit at any point and in any thread, not only in main method and in main thread." is a bit moot; it wouldn't have to be _only_ a return code? Other languages like C/C++ and C# support both approaches.

Answer (score 6):

An exit code of 0 means it completed normally, that is standard for all processes, not just java. The value is not returning from the main method (it's void) but from the JVM itself.

A different value can be specified, e.g. `System.exit(1)` to indicate some error condition, and the program stops.