# Is break still necessary after System.exit(0)?

Tags: java, switch-statement, exit

In a game I'm building, the user is given some options from which they can choose by pressing a number. A switch statement then runs the relevant method. One of the options is to exit the game, which I do by running `System.exit(0)`. I was wondering, if the break after the exit is still useful, and if so, why? And is there a difference if the `exit` is the last option in the switch statement, or not?

Code goes as follows:

```
switch(choice) {
    case 1: getEntityOverview();
        break;
    case 2: worldMap.PrintMap();
        break;
    case 3: moveAllOnInput();
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("You are exiting the game, "
            + "thanks for playing!");
        System.exit(0);
        break;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not necessary. Although—personally—I couldn't remove it due to my coding OCD.

Comment: Would put break as well / preferably not use `System.exit()` in the first place because regular flow control can do the same in a cleaner / more expected / symmetrical way. It's just a regular method (which happens to kill the program) and I would treat it that way when it comes to `switch` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need this `break` statement.

From the javadoc of class `System` :

> public static void exit(int status) 
>   Terminates the currently running
>   Java Virtual Machine.

This ends the execution of your application, your program exits, and no further instruction will be executed, unless you registered a `Shutdown Hook`.

Even a `finally` block won't get executed.

Hence, the `case` position where you put `System.exit`, will make no difference.

Comment: I'm unsure how I'd see a `finally` block inside a `switch` statement. I've seen it a lot in `try/catch` but never in `switch`. Could you point me to a resource that mentions this?

Comment: Oh well, I was just stating that System.exit does bypass many things, even "final" things. Sure, without a "try" , you never get a finally, so it wasn't relevant to your special case :)

Answer (score 0):

A `break` prevents a 'fall through' to the next `case` item. The `break` is not required here for two reasons:

- The option in question is the last item in the `switch` statement so there is nothing to fall through to
- Even if there was another item below, it will never 'fall through' anyway, as `System.exit()` does not return as it terminates the application (+/- various hooks)

Perhaps the question means *'does `System.exit()` ever return?'* (in which case if it were not the last item in a `switch` statement, a `break` might be required).

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)):

> [`System.exit()`] Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination. This method calls the `exit` method in class `Runtime`. *This method never returns normally*.
>
> The call `System.exit(n)` is effectively equivalent to the call: `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(n)`

I don't much like that 'normally'. `Runtime.exit` has the same 'normally'. I suspect this is however a reference to the fact they can throw an exception, in which case the absence of a `break` is not an issue. Jon Skeet does not appear to be concerned about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715967/when-should-we-call-system-exit-in-java).

That said, there is nothing to *prevent* you putting the `break` statement there. Indeed it may be a good plan in case someone adds another item after, then someone else swaps `System.exit()` for something that might return, e.g. a call to something saying *'Are you sure you want to quit'*?